# Input connector for GeoEvent that gets data from website that requires login credentials

Tags: real-time, geoevent-processor

I am trying to figure out a way to set up GeoEvent so that it polls a website that requires logging in, and then downloading the data.

Is there a way that GeoEvent can do this automatically?

I'm sure that I'm not the first one to attempt something like this with geoevent.

Does anyone know where I could find an input connector that will do this (and how to set it up)?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the input connectors support authentication when accessing feeds.

If you go to Site --> Connectors and search for the relevant input connector you want to add the authentication option against.  Best practise would be to make a copy of the connector so you have one for unsecure feeds and one for your particular authentication method.

In the configure properties, change the transport to an authentication method such as HTTP-Basic Authentication.

Configure the properties to expose the username and password as 'shown properties'

[image]

[image]

[image]

These images are taken from [this blog post](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2015/05/26/configure-your-geoevent-10-3-connector-to-use-a-secure-georss-feed/) which goes into more detail specifically around ingesting a secure RSS feed, but the same applies for majority of the input connectors.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was able to get it to work. I need to keep playing around with it to get the output that I need. Thanks again!

Comment: @nat_dude Don't forget to click the Accept checkmark (green tick) if this solved your problem.